# Build two slightly different projects from one code in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, build, qt5, qmake

I have a Qt project and I want to be able to build two slightly different executables - GUI and SimplifiedGUI. In the second one some of the tabs and the buttons will be hidden.

All the settings for the Simplified exe will be in an if statement and I need a way to make the boolean expression in this if statement True of False depends on what I want to build. I want to do this without changing the code, because the version control will be affected by that. The simplest way I imagine it is as a somehow build in command line argument, but I don't know how to do that.

Do you have some ideas and proposals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use preprocessor symbols for conditional compilation:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifdef SIMPLE_GUI_FLAG
constexpr bool simple = true;
#else
constexpr bool simple = false;
#endif

int main() {
    if (simple) std::cout << "simple";
}
```

For gcc you can invoke it with `-DSIMPLE_GUI_FLAG` to have the symbol `SIMPLE_GUI_FLAG` defined, it is not defined otherwise.

PS: This is perhaps opinion based, but I would try to keep the code that is affected by the preprocessor as little as possible (hence the `bool simple` in the above code). If you want to make it easier for the compiler to detect dead paths (consider `simple == false` in the above example) you can use `if constexpr`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! Could you tell me how to define the SIMPLE_GUI_FLAG with MinGW?

Comment: @Rufledore basically wingw is gcc for windows, i'd expect that it is also `-DNAME_OF_THE_SYMBOL`

Comment: Just to add. In QT5 it the symbol SIMPLE_GUI_FLAG, could be defined in the pro file as follows: DEFINE += SIMPLE_GUI_FLAG